# Server not displaying SVG in href

Tags: svg, iis-7.5

I use IIS 7.5 Server to generate my SVG file, this is ok.
I use SVG image to link another SVG file, and theres is the problem with my server.

I use

```
<image xlink:href="http://localhost:55555/SVG/ppqs.svg" x="99.05161" y="48" width="76" height="86"></image>
```

And all i got is a image with a cutted document.

If I test the URI, it is ok, the image is downloaded.

I have the correct mimetype `svg+xml` in server manager.

Comment: This sounds like it would be more of a browser issue than a server issue.  Have you tried it in multiple browsers?

Comment: I use visual studio so i have to use iis

Comment: That isn't a true statement, you can develop in visual studio and deploy to any webserver with most technologies.  However, what I'm saying is that it sounds like the server is fine, but the browser viewing the svg file isn't rendering it properly.  Try looking at the file in other browsers to see if that is the case.

Comment: i think the problem is from server, because i placed the file in my cloud and href is uri and it worked fine

Comment: i tried on firefox and explorer, same result